# How can I write part of dictionary value string as headers to csv file in python? Is there a better way?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary that uses log file names as keys. When reading through a text file if it contains a value I was searching for, it saves the entire line as a new value in the list of values for that key(log file name).
I.e Key: logFile0  Value: [Val1 5, Val2 3, Val3 72]. 
 I want to output to a csv file the values as headers and which log file it was found and the value.

```
  Key            |         Value
  log1           |    [Value_name Val_num], [Value1_name Val_num]
  log2           |    [Value1_name Val_num], [Value3_name Valu_num]
  log3           |    [Value2_name Val_num], [Value3_name Val_num]
```

I want it to be displayed in the csv file where for each time the value was found in the log file, it's value is displayed as:

```
    Value_name    |    Value1_name   |   Value2_name  |  Value3_name
log1      val_num |      val_num     |                | 
log2              |        val_num   |                |     val_num
log3              |                  |      val_num   |      val_num
```

Does anybody know how to do this? Or is there a better way to store all of this information and then display?

Comment: What code have you attempted?

Comment: A better way than what?

Comment: Thank you! I figured out another path with all of the data I needed to store. I just ended up using a class. I couldn't post the code or else I would have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach:

```
import csv
d = {"log1":[[0,"Val_num"],[1,"Val_num"]],
     "log2":[[1,"Val_num"],[3,"Val_num"]],
     "log3":[[2,"Val_num"],[3,"Val_num"]]}
```

I made a dictionary. Use yours but the "Val_num" are meant to be the actual numbers. The first number is the value_name e.g. 1 -> Value1_name

```
headers = ["Log File","Value_num","Value1_num","Value2_num","Value3_num"]
log1Row = ["log1","","","",""]
log2Row = ["log2","","","",""]
log3Row = ["log3","","","",""]
```

Here I simply initialised the rows to be written into the csv file.

```
for i in d["log1"]:
    log1Row[i[0] + 1] = i[1]
for i in d["log2"]:
    log2Row[i[0] + 1] = i[1]
for i in d["log3"]:
    log3Row[i[0] + 1] = i[1]
```

Now I am going to iterate over each key in the dictionary and append them into the arrays. The `+ 1` is needed as the array position for where theses numbers begin from is index 1 not 0 as this is the word "log".

```
with open("file.csv","w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerow(log1Row)
    writer.writerow(log2Row)
    writer.writerow(log3Row)
```

Just open the file to write to and write these rows.

Hopefully this works as long as your dictionary follows the way mine does.

Let me know of any erros.

Thank you.